# Mudar o CultureInfo em MVC5 / C# e Multi-Tenancy

Tags: c#, mvc, multi-tenancy, culture

Boa tarde pessoal! Estou trabalhando com MVC5 e preciso de uma ajuda na seguinte situação.. Tenho uma view que contém um seletor de idiomas, e que precisa alterar dinamicamente o conteúdo após selecionar o idioma desejado. Já tenho os arquivos .resx e capturando o idioma "setado" no select no entanto o conteúdo da página não é traduzido. Após alterar o CurrentUICulture estou dando um "return View()".

Tenho na view:

```
  <div class="form-group" >
     <select id="idioma"  onchange="VerificarIdioma()" class="form-control" style=" border-color: #FFFFFF;">
       <option id="pt-BR" ng-selected="selected">Português (Brasil)</option>
       <option id="es-CL">Español (Chile)</option>
       <option id="es-ES">Español (España)</option>
       <option id="en-US">English (USA)</option>
     </select>
  </div>
```

E pensei em usar no arquivo .cs do Tenant o seguinte:

```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Onde "en-US" deverá ser o item selecionado no select.

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?